# Setting a Breakpoint in GDB

Tags: gdb, breakpoints

I have a function that returns a pointer:

```
static void *find_fit(size_t asize);
```

I would like to set a breakpoint in gdb, but when I type this function name, I get one of these errors:

```
break *find_fit
Function "*find_fit" not defined
```

or

```
break find_fit
Function "find_fit" not defined
```

I can easily set break point on a function that returns something other than a pointer, but when the function does return a pointer, gdb doesn't seem to want to break on it.

Anybody see what is going on?  Thanks!

Comment: Sorry.  C++     kkkkkkkkkkkkkk

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like for some reason, gdb isn't handling C++ name mangling correctly. Normally you don't have to touch anything for this to work. You can try `show language`. Typically it's set to `auto`. You can also try manually setting it with `set language c++`.

To test, you can just type

```
b 'find<tab>
```

(that's the tab character, not the characters "`<tab>`") and it should try to autocomplete the name of the function for you. In C++ you need the argument types to know the function, but that doesn't 100% fit with what you're seeing because if you give gdb a function name without arguments, it'll usually do the right thing or prompt you for which version of a function you want. You aren't seeing either of those.